# Java Canvas drawImage Flashes

Tags: java, swing, awt

I always look for questions in StackOverflow, but I do not seem to find an answer for this one.

I'm using Java to create an application with Swing forms. I have added a Canvas AWT component to a JFrame.

I preload an image from the DB, draw it into the canvas and then set the JFrame as visible.

Problem is the image will flash: It is shown for some miliseconds, then, the JFrame is repainted.

Why does this happen? I tried to override the `paint()` method in the JFrame as well, and draw the image each time `paint` is called. But it is not working this way.

`Button Frame` (main frame) - (replace `final String imgPath` with a sample image of your choice)

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ButtonFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ButtonFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("View Image");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(59, 59, 59)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(44, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(70, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        final String imgPath = "/tmp/img.png";

        try
        {
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(imgPath));

            ImgFrame imgFrame = new ImgFrame();
            imgFrame.setImage(bi);
            imgFrame.setVisible(true);

//            imgFrame.setImageInCanvas(bi);

        } catch (IOException x) {}
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ButtonFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ButtonFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ButtonFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ButtonFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ButtonFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

`ImageFrame` (frame where the image is shown)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ImgFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    BufferedImage bi;

    public ImgFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void setImage(BufferedImage bi)
    {
        this.bi = bi;
    }

    public void setImageInCanvas(BufferedImage bi)
    {
        canvas1.getGraphics().drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        setImageInCanvas(bi);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        canvas1 = new java.awt.Canvas();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(canvas1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 266, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(canvas1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 155, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private java.awt.Canvas canvas1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Video example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53gOV_BD8J8Mm10LW5CN2E3M2M/view

---

**The problem has been solved:**

I have overriden the `paint` method in JFrame like this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Where `bi` is a BufferedImage.

Then, the Canvas was overlapping the Form, since it was set to fit the JFrame, and the image was not displaying. I have removed it (the AWT Canvas) and the Image is now displaying in the background.

Thank you very much!

Special thanks to Dodd10x and Andrew Thompson.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) But `canvasImagen.getGraphics()..` that does not bode well.  It is almost always the wrong way to go about painting a component.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Creating MCVE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: MCVE created and video example (in higher quality) of the problem added.

Comment: Looking at you new code, where are you overriding http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics) ?

Comment: @Dodd10x , I tried overriding it, and as it did not function properly, I removed it.

Comment: You have to override it.  It won't work otherwise.

Comment: I have overriden it. Same result. MCVE Source code updated.

Comment: Instead, you should call drawImage on the Graphics g object passed in the paint method.  Get rid of your setImageInCanvas method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92080/discussion-between-jesus-gonzalez-and-dodd10x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not mix Swing and AWT.  First thing to change is switch from Canvas to JComponent if you are displaying in a JFrame.

Comment: The course teacher required us only using AWT Canvas along with Swing. Thanks for that point.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Can you use Frame instead of JFrame?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. He wants the image to be drawn in a AWT Canvas. I'm going to try using just Frame instead of JFrame right now and tell you what the result is.

Comment: *"He wants the image to be drawn in a AWT Canvas"*  He needs to update (or retire).  Most of us that ever used AWT components have forgotten the fine details!

Comment: I have tried with Frame instead of JFrame. Same result.

Comment: Since JDK 7 build 19 mixing of heavyweight (AWT) and lightweight (Swing) components is [supported](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).